# Let $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^3+3x^2+3x+5}$, then what is $f^{(99)}(-1)$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> Let $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^3+3x^2+3x+5}$, then what is $f^{(99)}(-1)$?

By letting $g(x)=x^3+3x^2+3x+5$, it is easy to see that $g'(-1) = g''(-1) = 0$, and so $f'(-1) = f''(-1) = f'''(-1) = 0$.

However, I have no idea how to compute $f^{(n)}(-1)$ for any positive integer $n$, and in particular for $n=99$.

Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: To compute high derivatives at $x=-1$, change variables $y=x+1$ so you can compute derivatives at $0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $t=x+1$. Then:

$$ f(x)= {1\over (x+1)^3+4} = {1\over 4}{1\over 1+{t^3\over 4}}=$$

$$ = {1\over 4}\Big(1-{t^3\over 4}+ \big({t^3\over 4}\big)^2-\big({t^3\over 4}\big)^3+...\Big)$$

So $$f^{(99)}(x) = -{1\over 4}{99!\over 4^{33}} + t(...)\implies f^{(99)}(-1) = -{99!\over 4^{34}}$$

Answer (score 6):

Note that in a neighbourhood of $x=-1$,
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{x^3+3x^2+3x+5}=\frac{1/4}{1+\frac{(x+1)^3}{4}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(-1)}{n!}(x+1)^n.$$
Now recall that for $|t|<1$,
$$\frac{1}{1+t}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n t^n.$$
Can you take it form here?